# ArcMap 'go back to previous extent' doesn't

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I often use the "go back to previous extent" i.e. the back button when navigating my models in ArcMap.  Alas for some reason it seems to have fixed on a certain location as my "previous extent", no matter how many places I visit in the interim.

Is this a bug or is there a bizarre setting somewhere I've triggered?

Comment: Does this happen in all your instances of arcmap or just in one MXD? Also which version of Arcgis desktop are you using? (please include it in the tags) I hate to sound cliche, but have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Restarting ArcMap fixed it :)  Sorry for polluting gis.se with such a silly question.  Should I delete it?!

Comment: No, you can leave it as it will help find future readers an answer when they might have the same problem. You can add an answer to your own question and mark it as the accepted answer.